# Problems drawing Windows 10 Caption Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, visual-styles

I'm having problems drawing Windows 10 themed Window Caption Buttons using the VisualStyleRenderer class.

My problem is that I can't figure out which Theme Class to use.
I tried `Window` and `CompositedWindow::Window`, however, none of those actually contain Windows 10 themed buttons as I found out using [this msstyle editor](https://github.com/nptr/msstyleEditor).

Which Theme Class contains Windows 10 themed Caption Buttons?

How it looks now:

[image: Windows 7 themed button]

How I want it to look:

[image: Windows 10 themed caption buttons]

How I'm drawing the buttons:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("Window", 18 /*WP_CLOSEBUTTON*/, 1 /*CBS_NORMAL*/);
    var size = renderer.GetPartSize(e.Graphics, ThemeSizeType.True);
    renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(10, 10, size.Width, size.Height));
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at the Chrome source and see how they do it.

Comment: Those are probably rendered using the [Segoe MDL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) font.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I looked through chrome and firefox source, it looks like they both draw the caption buttons similarly by using DrawThemeBackground with `Window` theme, but I could have overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Window` class you are using. This is the legacy GDI Window that is composited without a composition engine.

The `DWM` Desktop Window Manager composites every window, as every window is just a DirectX surface. You need to use the `DWMWindow` class as opposed to the `Window` class from `aero.msstyles`.

[image]

Notice how there are multiple glyphs for each DPI: 96, 120, 144, etc.

Comment: Can I still draw the buttons using a VisualStyleRenderer or DrawThemeBackground? If so, what Part IDs and State IDs do I have to use?

Comment: @thebear8 It's a little more complicated. I don't have a C# sample handy, but you need to use `LoadLibraryEx`, `OpenThemeData`, and `GetThemeStream` to get a pointer to a PNG file in memory that contains all the modern aero glyphs. You can then use `GetThemeRect` to find the correct rectangle of the glyph you need. For more info, see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222021/getthemestream-usage

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.